# batch: if statement with string comparison always returns true

Tags: batch-file

```
if "x%1" == "x" (
goto :l2
)
:l2
echo doskey %1>>startup.cmd
```

Tried with and without parentheses on both the condition and the goto, also tried without quotation marks and of course goto on the same line - it always returns true.

Comment: Are you passing an argument to your batch script? `%1` is the value of the first argument passed to the script; if you're not passing an argument, the if statement will always be true. What are you trying to accomplish with your `if` statement?

Comment: no it does not - but exactly same code is executed indifferent of what it evaluates to.

Comment: Do you care to elaborate on that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a very silly error :-)

If the condition is true you GOTO the label.

If the condition is false you don't GOTO, but you fall through to the next line which happens to be your label.

Same result either way!

Other issues -

1) I think your logic is reversed. I believe you only want to GOTO :l2 if %1 is defined, you have the reverse.

2) A %1 value of `"A&B"` (including quotes) would fail. Better to use `"%~1"` instead of `"%1"`

3) There is no need for the x in your comparison.

Easily fixed:

```
if "%~1" neq "" goto :l2
exit /b
:l2
echo doskey %1>>startup.cmd
```

You really don't need the goto:

```
if "%~1" neq "" echo doskey %1>>startup.cmd
```